# Kalman Filter, accuracy of the current estimate

Tags: kalman-filter

I am running experiments on the kalman filter, with a particular interest on the covariance Matrix. I am using the formulas given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter and something which seems weird to me is that the covariance matrix does not seem to be influenced at all by the measurements, because the formulas using the measurement $z_k$ concerns only the corrected state and not the corrected covariance.

My specific concern is that since I need to compute the "quality" of the current value (it's expected accuracy) I was thinking about using the covariance matrix to get this information. But if this value is not influenced by the measurements, I think it is not a very good idea...

I didn't write too much detailed informations in order to keep a readable question, but I can give more details if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The covariance matrix *is* influenced by a measurement.  However you are absolutely correct in your excellent observation that the measured *value* does not affect the covariance matrix.  Only the measurement *noise* affects the covariance matrix.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840662/an-explanation-of-the-kalman-filter/859417) for more details.

The diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are the variances of the corresponding states and can be used as a measure of the quality of the estimate.