# Why state vector equation is one time forward in Kalman FIlter?

Tags: statistics, kalman-filter

After looking various sources ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840662/an-explanation-of-the-kalman-filter)),  I have found following equations for system description  in kalman filter:

Measurement Equation as: 
$$
y_t=C_t x_t+r_t \tag{1}
$$

and state vector equation as: 
$$x_{t+1} = A_t x_t  + q_t \tag{2}$$

where $r_t \sim N(0, R_t)$ and $q_t \sim N(0, Q_T)$.

I have simple question. Why in equation 2 state vector equation is considered for $x_{t+1}$? Should we have $q_{t+1}$ on the right hand side? What would be the implication for the model if we have considered following equation for state vector equation: 
$$x_{t} = A_t x_{t-1}  + q_t$$

---

**Implication of equation 2 and 3**:

If we consider equation 1 and 2, and given the filtration $F_{t-1}$, then in equation 1, only $r_t$ is random variable because $x_t$ is completely determined because $x_t = f(x_{t-1}, q_{t-1})$ but same can not be said about the $x_t$ in equation 1 if we consider equation 1 and 3.  In equation 3, $x_t = f(x_{t-1}, q_t)$, it means that given the filtration $F_{t-1}$, $x_t$ is still random variable.

It means conditional expectation of $y_t$ considering (1) and (2) will be: 
\begin{align}
E(y_t|F_{t-1}) =& C_t \, x_t + E(r_t|F_{t-1})\\
=&C_tx_t  \tag{4} 
\end{align}
Since, $x_t$ is completely determined given $F_{t-1}$.

If we considered equation (1) and equation (3), then conditional expectation of $y_t$ is :

\begin{align}
E(y_t|F_{t-1}) =& C_t \, E(x_t|F_{t-1}) + E(r_t|F_{t-1})\\
=&C_t E(x_t|F_{t-1}) \tag{5}
\end{align}

I think both the expression in equation 4 and 5 are different.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not a great problem if $x_{t+1}$ depends on $q$ at time $t$ or $t+1$. It is just a convention, since it is nicer to have a dynamical system where the right hand side depends only on the variable evaluated at the previous time instant. The forms: $$x_{t+1} = f(x_t, q_t)$$ or $$x_{t} = f(x_{t-1}, q_{t-1}),$$ are equivalent.

Comment: @the_candyman Actually in equation 2, we have $x_{t+1}$ and $q_t$). I am asking why not $x_{t+1}$ and $q_{t+1}$?

Comment: As I said, $$x_{t+1} = f(x_t, q_{t+1})$$ is unusual, since it is preferable to write quantities at time $t+1$ as a function of quantities at time $t$. It is a convention, and IMHO it keeps everything cleaner... the future ($t+1$) depends only on the past ($t$).

Comment: Anyway, if you really need this, let's pose $v_t = q_{t+1}$. Then, $$x_{t+1} = f(x_{t}, q_{t+1}) = f(x_{t}, v{t}).$$